# aws s3 sdk list objects by multiple prefixes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

is there any possible way/endpoint to use sdk to list objects by multiple prefixes?
i have a file in a specific folder (will call it original for now) with an uuid identifier and 2 other files with the same uuid in different folders.
i want to retrieve them by the path+uuid identifier.
it goes like this
i retrieve 10 original files and want to match for each file the 2 different files that have the same uuid ( i have the path they are in)
how can i retrieve this thing?
i thought about using

```
    return s3Connection
  .listObjectsV2({
    Bucket: destinationBucket,
    Prefix: path,
    Delimiter: '/',
    MaxKeys: maxKeys,
  })
  .promise();
```

but it does not support multiple prefixes

Comment: No, if you need different prefixes you have to do multiple requests, one for each prefix. What do you need to do with the results of those requests? If you already know their path (ie for `original/someuuid` they are `somepath1/someuuid` and `somepath2/someuuid`) why would you need an additional `listObjects` request?  Another way could be if all three paths have a common prefix, you could just query that common prefix and then filter on the client side. Of course, depending on the data on your S3 there may also be many unwanted results ...

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue and couldn't change the key prefixes. It's pretty easy to do multiple calls, just create a prefixes array and then loop through them. All the rest of your code should be the same.

```
const prefixes = ['path1/data1/', 'path2/data2/', 'path3/data3/'];

prefixes.forEach(async (prefix) => {

    const S3Params = {
        Bucket: 'bucketName',
        Delimiter: '/',
        Prefix: prefix,
    };

    const res = await s3Client
        .send(new ListObjectsCommand(S3Params));

    const s3Items = res.Contents
}
```